# Using regular expression to cut/paste lines in sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

What's the best way to move the "data-filter-tags" to one line above using sublime or other methods?

```
<div class="col-4">
   <a class="app-list__item">
        <div class="display-4" data-filter-tags="angle-down">
            <i class="fal fa-angle-down"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
   <a class="app-list__item">
        <div class="display-4" data-filter-tags="angle-left">
            <i class="fal fa-angle-left"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The result will look like this:

```
<div class="col-4">
   <a class="app-list__item" data-filter-tags="angle-down">
        <div class="display-4">
            <i class="fal fa-angle-down"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
   <a class="app-list__item" data-filter-tags="angle-left">
        <div class="display-4">
            <i class="fal fa-angle-left"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `(<[^>]*)(>\s*.*?)(\s*data-filter-tags="[^"]*")` replace with `$1$3$2`

Comment: Can you please explain whats $1$3$2

Comment: It's a reference to the text captured in the groups from the original pattern. I'll post it as an answer with explanation for more clarification, give me a few minutes.

Comment: You're welcome! I've added an explanation in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/QN8gl2/1)

```
(<[^>]*)(>\s*.*?)(\s*data-filter-tags="[^"]*")
```

Replacement: `$1$3$2`

---

### Results

#### Input

```
<div class="col-4">
   <a class="app-list__item">
        <div class="display-4" data-filter-tags="angle-down">
            <i class="fal fa-angle-down"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
   <a class="app-list__item">
        <div class="display-4" data-filter-tags="angle-left">
            <i class="fal fa-angle-left"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

#### Output

```
<div class="col-4">
   <a class="app-list__item" data-filter-tags="angle-down">
        <div class="display-4">
            <i class="fal fa-angle-down"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
   <a class="app-list__item" data-filter-tags="angle-left">
        <div class="display-4">
            <i class="fal fa-angle-left"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

---

### Explanation

- `(<[^>]*)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `<` Match this literally
  - `[^>]*` Match any character except `>` any number of times
- `(>\s*.*?)` Capture the following into capture group 2

  - `>` Match this literally
  - `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
  - `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible (excludes newline characters)
- `(\s*data-filter-tags="[^"]*")` Capture the following into capture group 3

  - `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
  - `data-filter-tags="` Match this literally
  - `[^"]*` Match any character except `"` any number of times
  - `"` Match this literally

The replacement of `$1$3$2` simply reorders the captured text such that the third capture group is placed after the first, but before the second.

Comment: You have literally saved me hours of work, now I can give time to my kids :) Accepting your answer after the 3 min grace period.